# How does `apt remove` know which files should be removed?

Tags: apt, package-management, software-installation, dpkg, deb

I've just created a small DEB package, just to see how it works. My file structure was the following:

```
~/temp/myapp_1.0                                                                                                                   
▶ tree          
.
├── DEBIAN
│   ├── control
│   └── postinst
└── usr
    └── bin
        ├── myapp
        ├── myapp.deps.json
        ├── myapp.dll
        ├── myapp.pdb
        └── myapp.runtimeconfig.json
```

Basically, I created a Hello-World dotnet app.
My `control` file is just:

```
Package: myapp
Version: 1.0
Maintainer: marcin
Architecture: all
Description: demo
```

and my `postinst` is:

```
echo "echo (from postinst)"
```

I created DEB with `dpkg-deb --build myapp_1.0`, and then installed it with `sudo dpkg -i myapp_1.0.deb`

I see that `/usr/bin` contains all my app's files as expected, and the app works when invoked with `myapp`.

Then, I decided to remove it with `sudo apt remove myapp`. It removed all of the app's files from `/usr/bin`. My question is: how did it know which files belong to it? I thought it would remove just the binary `/usr/bin/myapp`, but it also got rid of the `myapp.dll`, and all the rest.

Is it always the case that `apt remove something` will remove the program completely (and `apt purge something` will also remove all configs)? How does it know where to look? Will it also remove files that my app would create during runtime?

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text. Copy the text here and use code formatting instead.

Comment: @muru Right, I fixed that. I miss the syntax-coloring though :)

Answer (score 3):

"*How does it know which files to remove?*" is exactly the same question as "*How does it know which files to install?*" You gave apt/dpkg that information in the package structure.

Files created at runtime must be removed by a prerm script in order to meet the Debian standard of *idempotence*: `apt install foo` followed by `apt remove foo` must return your system to state before the install.

Two exceptions:

1. Files in /etc are removed by "purge", not by "remove".
2. Files in /home are never removed by apt/dpkg. Those belong to the users.

Apt/dpkg does not have any setting to remove only a binary and leave other (non- /etc) files in place. If other packages depend upon a library, then package that library separately.

Comment: Thanks. One question. When I install a .deb file it obviously knows where to put the files, because this information is in the .deb itself. However, after installation, I may delete the .deb file. Where does `apt` store information about which files belong to which program (so that it can remove them later when running`apt remove`)?

Comment: It stores it in `/var/lib/dpkg/info`.

Answer (score 1):

Once you install your deb file, do this:

```
dpkg -L <packagename>
```

You will see that it lists all the content of your package. This means that the system knows which files were installed by a package and therefore knows what to remove.

This information is found in the following location:

```
/var/lib/dpkg/info
```

For each package there exists a file named packagename.list containing exactly the same information as the output of `dpkg -L` earlier.